# How to handle vulnerabilities in general

Tags: frontend, backend

I'm new to javascript frameworks and I'm currently working on a MEAN project. At first I'm trying to understand the safest way to handle vulnerabilities on both back and front end. For example:

I cloned a back/front end project and after installing dependencies the following vulnerabilities found.

Back-end

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvGjw.png)

Front-end

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHxNU.png)

I have a lot of questions but my main concern is the right procedure for such projects to follow. For example:

- Do I first have to update packages to the Wanted version?
- Do I have to fix all vulnerabilities, to progress.
- Is that dependable from other factors?

Thank you for your help and support

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check each package before you install it - if it's requirements are met by your machine e.g do you have the needed version of node installed?

There is also npm outdated command that you can run to print a list of all packages which are out of date

The thing you could do aboutfixing the vulnerabilites  is to try the npm audit, for moment-in-time security review of your project's dependency tree.The audit report that will be generated will give you recommendations and commands for troubleshooting.

Another thing you could do for each package with vulnerability flag - check it's repo.There could an existing issue related to the vulnerability.

[This](https://itnext.io/fixing-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-less-than-3-mins-a53af735261d) might be worth reading.

Comment: This project was created with node version 10 on another machine. My node version is v1 Should the node version be the same?
Additionally when i run npm audit i see recommendations of the commands need to run in order to solve the problem. However some of them are major updates which might potentially break the code.
So in this case which option should i choose:
- Should i change node version to 10 and then npm i?
- Leave node version 12 and update all recommended dependencies (including SEMVER WARNINGS)?
- Update only the outdated packages
Is there some other procedure which i'm missing

Comment: don't you have a link to your code? so i can see what commands you are referring too. i can't tell you now what to first. may i see your code?

Comment: I added code in git for you can have a look if you can.  [github.com/paniklas/vilapp] Thank you for your help!